# Using Popup menu giving ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am using popup menu in my app and it is crashing after on click, giving ClassNotFound Exception.
I had used the following code

```
menu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
  menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(HTTTPGet.this, view);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(HTTTPGet.this);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu);
        popupMenu.show();
    }
});
```

here is the onmenuitemclick method

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.home:
    Intent home=new Intent(this,HTTTPGet.class);
    startActivity(home);
    return true;
case R.id.schedule:
    Intent schedule=new Intent(this,Schedule.class);
    startActivity(schedule);
    return true;
case R.id.manual:
    Intent manual=new Intent(this,Schedule.class);
    startActivity(manual);
    return true;
default:
return false;
}
}
```

after clicking on imageview app is getting crashed and the logcat is

```
    09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.PopupMenu
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at com.teapoyinfotech.cvv.HTTTPGet$1.onClick(HTTTPGet.java:99)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
09-30 16:19:31.560: E/AndroidRuntime(6294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does I need to add anything to above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PopupMenu` is available from Android API 11.

So just check your minimum SDK version in manifest file. And atleast  you have to set minimum SDK version `11`.

For more information read documents http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

Answer (score 1):

PopupMenu was introduced in the API level 11

Looks like you are compiling your project with 11+, minumum API is less than 11, and launching on device with android version less than 11.

This might cause ClassNotFoundException

The decicions are as follow:
1) Increase your minimum API level to 11 in your AndroidManifest.xml (thus that makes it impossible to launch application on devices with android version less than 11
2) Use PopupMenu from android support v7 library (android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu)
In order to get this library, please refer to:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Hope one of this things will fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

in spite of specifying only `this` give `activityname.this` while calling the intent in your onmenuitemclick method. hope it works

Comment: It doesn't work. Not useful answer. Just read logcat very clearly and properly.

Comment: :( ok i ll crosscheck.

Comment: have define your imageview id in your activity?